# Caculating function running time

Tags: javascript, time

I want to calculate the average running time of a function in JavaScript like this:

```
time = 0;

while(1000) {
  time1 = performance.now();
  function();
  time2 = performance.now();
  time += (time2-time1);
}
```

The problem is that only the first loop the time interval is about `60ms` and the following loop the interval is nearly zero. 
So I changed the code to:

```
time1 = performance.now();

while(1000000) {     
    function();
}

time2 = performance.now();
time = (time2-time1);
```

The running time is about `4 seconds`.

I guess maybe it is because of the automatic optimisation.

If it is this case, are there any approaches to close the optimisation?

Comment: I would assume just throwing in an arbitrary argument would help, i.e. `function(i);` with the loop iteration count being `i`. Just an assumption though, not tested this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've most likely caused the browser to hand off that code to its JIT compiler. The first run is always through the interpreter (slow). Hot code gets put through the JIT and the resulting native (fast) code is then used.

This is automatic and generally out of your hands to control. You can disable the Firefox JIT compiler by using 'with' in a script.

```
with({}) {}
```

Add this to the top of your script and the JIT will be disabled for your script.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [console.time](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.time) and [console.endTime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.timeEnd) function to calculate the running time.

example:

```
 console.time('profile 1');
   for ( var i=0; i < 100000; i++) {
    var arr = new Array();
   }
  console.timeEnd('profile 1');//profile 1: 108.492ms 

  console.time('profile 2');
   for ( var i=0; i < 100000; i++) {
    var arr = [];
   }
  console.timeEnd('profile 2');//profile 2: 81.907ms
```